# Seaborn light_palette custom length

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to make a sequential palette using `seaborn` of a custom length.  `seaborn` provides both `light_palette` and `dark_palette` which look very similar to what I'd like, but I need a custom length of steps.  I also need to match `seaborn`'s default color schemes.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.palplot(sns.light_palette(sns.color_palette()[0]))
```

[image: <code>light_palette</code> of constant length]

I have tried several solutions:

Attempt 1 - using `seaborn.cubehelix_palette`, but I fail to be able to match the colors provided by `seaborn.color_palette()`

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.palplot(sns.cubehelix_palette(7,start=1,rot=0,dark=0.22,light=0.8))
```

[image: Attempt 1 output]

Attempt 2 - Use half of a `seaborn.diverging_palette`, but I can't get the colors to match either.  The default color scheme puts out a blue that is RGB(76,114,176) or hex (#4C72B0) or HSL (217° 40% 49%), but when entering these parameters I get the wrong colors.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(217.,217.,n=7,s=40,l=49))
```

[image: Attempt 2 Bad Plot]

Comment: what does "length of steps" mean? number of colors? perceptual distance between each color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the palette with `N` colors by specifying this number in the call to the palette.

```
sns.palplot(sns.light_palette(sns.color_palette()[0],N))
```

[image]